# How does Caffe determine test set accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, caffe, pycaffe

Using the BVLC reference AlexNet file, I have been training a CNN against a training set I created.  In order to measure the progress of training, I have been using a rough method to approximate the accuracy against the training data.  My batch size on the test net is 256.  I have ~4500 images.  I perform 17 calls to solver.test_nets[0].forward() and record the value of solver.test_nets[0].blobs['accuracy'].data (the accuracy of that forward pass).  I take the average across these.  My thought was that I was taking 17 random samples of 256 from my validation set and getting the accuracy of these random samplings.  I would expect this to closely approximate the true accuracy against the entire set.  However, I later went back and wrote a script to go through each item in my LMDB so that I could generate a confusion matrix for my entire test set.  I discovered that the true accuracy of my model was significantly lower than the estimated accuracy.  For example, my expected accuracy of ~75% dropped to ~50% true accuracy.  This is a far worse result than I was expecting.

[My assumptions match the answer given here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138334/what-does-caffe-train-test-net-output-mean)

Have I made an incorrect assumption somewhere?  What could account for the difference?  I had assumed that forward() function gathered a random sample, but I'm not so sure that was the case.  blobs.['accuracy'].data returned a different result (though usually within a small range) everytime, so this is why I assumed this.

Answer (score 0):

> I had assumed that forward() function gathered a random sample, but I'm not so sure that was the case.  blobs.['accuracy'].data returned a different result (though usually within a small range) everytime, so this is why I assumed this.

The `forward()` function from Caffe does not perform any random sampling, it will only fetch the next batch according to your `DataLayer`. E.g., in your case `forward()` will pass the next 256 images in your network. Performing this 17 times will pass sequentially `17x256=4352` images.

> Have I made an incorrect assumption somewhere?  What could account for the difference?

Check that the script that goes through your whole LMDB performs the same data pre-processing as during training.